# Directed graphs and right kan extensions

Tags: category-theory

Let $D$ be the category with two objects, $E,V$ and a pair of maps $s,t : E \rightarrow V$. Consider the functor $K: \textbf{1} \rightarrow D$ where $\textbf{1}$ is the terminal category that and K picks out the object V. Consider a functor $F: \textbf{1} \rightarrow Set$ (i.e a Set).

I want to compute the right Kan extension of $F$ along $K$  using the end formula given here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kan_extension#Kan_extensions_as_coends

I have no problems finding out what the right Kan extension is on objects, but what is it on morphisms? I can't seem to figure this out, when I try it the arrows seem to go in the wrong direction.

Comment: The coend formula is obviously functorial. Are you using a different formula?

Comment: @ZhenLin I am sure it is functorial, but there is some part I am missing! I am indeed using the formula given there, so I would be very helpful if you could write down how the maps go just briefly. I am sure it is something obvious I am missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall the end formula for right Kan extension:
$$(\operatorname{Ran}_K F) d = \int_{{*} : \mathbb{1}} \mathcal{D} (d, K {*}) \pitchfork F {*}$$
Here, $X \pitchfork Y$ denotes the exponential object $Y^X$. Since we are integrating over $\mathbb{1}$ here, this just means that $(\operatorname{Ran}_K F) d = \mathcal{D} (d, K {*}) \pitchfork F {*}$. This is obviously functorial in $d$; it is *covariantly* functorial in $d$ because $\mathcal{D} (d, d')$ is *contravariantly* functorial in $d$ and $X \pitchfork Y$ is *contravariantly* functorial in $X$.

Comment: + A million if I could - now it is obvious, but before it wasn't. The thing that confused me was that I was identifying the exponential object with a indexed product. Of course this notion is a correct notion of an exponential object, but it hid that it is probably more productive to view it as functions from Y into X.